# new MailAddress() Exits out of method

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-mvc-5, mailaddress

I have a fairly weird issue that I can't wrap my head around.  So here is the code:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult SendEmail()
{
    SendRegisterEmail("Test", "Testagain", "lastTest");
    return View("Index");
}

public async Task<bool> SendRegisterEmail(string subject, string message, string to)
{
    var email = new Email();
    var mailAddress = new MailAddress(to);
    email.Subject = subject;
    email.Body = message;
    var mailAddressCollection = new MailAddressCollection();
    mailAddressCollection.Add(mailAddress);
    email.To = (mailAddressCollection);

    return await Send(email);
}
```

Now to prove my problem I broke down the code into single lines so I can see on which line it breaks.  Here is what I found:

When I debug this and I step into the `SendRegisterEmail` method, the line that says `var mailAddress = new MailAddress(to);` gets run and then it exits out the function and runs the line `return View("Index");` and the page loads up.  The weird thing is I added a logging method on to Send at the very end and that logging never gets hit.  I put a breakpoint on Send and it never got hit.  It is as if creation of email crashed, decided to exit out to the caller function and continued with the code.

I don't have a faintest clue as to why.

Comment: The value you assign to "to" is not a valid email address. This might cause it to exit the function and as it is asynchronous it runs the return View statement

Answer (score 2):

`SendRegisterEmail` method is asynchronous, you're not awaiting for it.

Currently, you start a fire-and-forget operation and `return View` instruction is executed while you're creating a new `MailAddress` instance.
Most probably it [throws](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/591bk9e8(v=vs.110).aspx) `FormatException` which you can't catch because the exception is thrown in another thread.

update your action method to

```
public async Task <ActionResult> SendEmail()
{
    await SendRegisterEmail("Test", "Testagain", "lastTest");
    return View("Index");
}
```

Also awaiting before the return is not really needed, you can change it to

```
public Task<bool> SendRegisterEmail(string subject, string message, string to)
{
    var email = new Email();
    // ... 
    return Send(email);
}
```

but that's not related to the problem you've got.

Comment: Ah, the reason it doesn't work now is because it doesn't like `"lastTest"` as a value, it wants a proper email address.

Comment: Why would you do that?  Send returns a true or false.